# Did I mess up my where clause? Getting unexpected results

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

```
$active_sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_campaign 
    WHERE status='blasting' 
    OR status='ready' 
    OR status='followup_hold' 
    OR status='initial_hold' 
    AND uid=:uid 
    ORDER BY status ASC");

$active_sth->bindParam(':uid', $_SESSION['uid']['id']);

$active_sth->execute();
```

I am positive $_SESSION['uid']['id'] = 7
but it will also pull results of id 10 or any other number.

Is my AND/OR clause written wrong?

Comment: It's good to see mysql questions where the OP is using bound parameters!

Comment: :-) it took me a year to come around.

Comment: @TecBrat Some people can learn, I hope we'll meet more of them ;)

Comment: I think one of the main problems is the entrenchment of old tutorials in Google search results.

Comment: It took me a long time too. It was thanks to THIS site that I finally made the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to write that is:

```
SELECT * FROM user_campaign 
WHERE status IN ('blasting', 'ready', 'followup_hold', 'initial_hold')
AND uid =: uid 
ORDER BY status ASC
```

You should use `IN` instead of that huge amount of `OR`s :)

Comment: Nice. I like this method the best.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, query is wrong

```
SELECT * FROM user_campaign 
WHERE (
    status='blasting' 
    OR status='ready' 
    OR status='followup_hold' 
    OR status='initial_hold'
)
AND uid=:uid 
ORDER BY status ASC
```

You have to group all `OR`s to make sure that row got one of this values, and separately check if it have given `uid`.